# Group membership pattern

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns

I am trying to figure out how to implement a group membership module for an app where the natural key for the group is its set of users.  Stated another way, any combination of users can only create a single group.

By way of example, let's say we have three users: UserA, UserB, and UserC.  Now let's say UserA starts a group with UserB.  We'll call it Group1.  If UserA attempts to start another group with UserB or UserB attempts to create a group with UserA, Group1 will be returned.  UserA, however, can still start a group with UserB and UserC since we do not yet have a group with that combination of users.  We'll call it Group2.

So the natural key for Group1 is UserA + UserB.

The natural key for Group2 is UserA + UserB + UserC.

Hopefully that makes sense.

The table contents for the above example would be:

```
User
=================
user_id  username
      1  UserA
      2  UserB
      3  UserC

Group
=========================
group_id  name    alt_key
       1  Group1  1,2
       2  Group2  1,2,3

Member
============================
member_id  group_id  user_id
        1         1        1
        2         1        2
        3         2        1
        4         2        2
        5         2        3
```

alt_key is a sorted list of user_ids.

Clearly this method is not very scalable so I improved it a bit by hashing the alt_key.  This made the key significantly smaller for larger groups, but since hashes aren't unique, it still requires lots of gymnastics to ensure that users cannot create duplicate groups.

Anyhow, I'm wondering if there's a pattern or better implementation that allows for an "unlimited" number of users per group without crazy queries to ensure group membership is unique.

**EDIT:** Why is the current solution not scalable?  For starters, sorting and hashing a list of user_ids of any scale is not fast or memory efficient.  Beyond that, while using a hash does significantly narrow my search, checking to see if a group of users exists is also very tricky.  I was just hoping someone knew of a better way.

Currently, I am limiting group sizes to mitigate the scalability issues but I wanted to avoid that if at all possible.

**EDIT:** Security is not really a concern.  The hash is purely being used as a way to narrow the search for group membership.  It is built using all internal integer ids and is never exposed through the API.  The current code (in Python 3.6):

```
hashlib.md5(marshal.dumps(deduplicated_and_sorted_user_id_iterable))
```

This, of course, contributes to the scalability issue as I have to bring all the ids into memory to sort and hash them.

Comment: In what sense is your solution not scalable? I.e. what are your scalability constraints that are not met by your solution?

Comment: Once a group is formed, can new people join the group and existing members depart? It seems not, but please confirm.

Comment: Groups are immutable.  Once you join, you're a member for life.  Here's hoping you really enjoy the group!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a long [Zobrist hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing) and assume that all collisions are true positives. Compute the hash with a formula like

```
HMAC-SHA256(SecretKey1,
            HMAC-SHA256(SecretKey2, UserA) XOR HMAC-SHA256(SecretKey2, UserB) XOR ...),
```

which doesn't require sorting or a lot of intermediate storage space. Treating `HMAC-SHA256` as a random oracle and assuming that `SecretKey[12]` and the intermediate computations stay secret, the probability of a collision given `2^64` groups (an extremely large number) is less than `2^-128`, which is so small that your database will almost certainly become corrupted before there's a false positive. (The outer `HMAC-SHA256` forestalls timing attacks and provides resistance against a stolen database.)

I'll think about whether it's possible to get rid of `SecretKey[12]` in a provably secure manner without adding a sorting requirement.

Comment: Interesting.  See original question edit for more follow-up information/thoughts.  Short version: security isn't important and the "thing" being hashed is a sorted list of integer ids.